# Marking older questions as duplicates

Tags: discussion, users, possible-duplicates

I was browsing through questions sorted by "active," starting from the last page (i.e. looking at *least* active questions), and I came across ["the printers is" vs. "the printers are"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1014/the-printers-is-vs-the-printers-are) which seems to make (debatably, I suppose it could just be considered related) [What does the butcher's (meaning the butcher's shop) become in the plural](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/70976/what-does-the-butchers-meaning-the-butchers-shop-become-in-the-plural) a duplicate.

The older question has no accepted answer and the OP's account is no longer with us. Regardless of what to do for this particular example, it got me wondering...

**What should we do in the case of a duplicate question that is much older, has no accepted answer, and has a "dead" asker?**

Possibilities that came to mind:

- Mark the *older* question as the duplicate
- Consider the older question simply "related" (even if it is, in truth, a duplicate) and link to it from the newer question
- Just leave the whole thing alone

Comment: These are different questions.  They are related inasmuch as they are about differences between singular and plural forms of things.  But the things in question are different things.

Comment: Marking older question will not make any sense. Second option suits me.

Comment: @Euan M "Regardless of what to do for this particular example..." My question is not about what to do regarding the questions I linked to.

Comment: I agree that your question was not what to do about the particular paired examples you gave.  But it is still an example of false-positive regarding claiming a non-duplicating pair as duplicates.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The question with answers that are actually useful is far more valid and important than a dusty old unanswered question. But duplicate linking helps improve search results, so closing the old question as a duplicate of the better question seems to be the best plan to me.

I double-checked my gut on this with an MSE search, and I found [this relevant answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/40391/187816) to a question asking what to do if you want to ask a question that has an old unanswered duplicate:
Firstly consider why the old one hasn't been answered (is it badly written, is it unanswerable, is it in the wrong place, etc).

> Ask your question, making sure you avoid the mistakes the old one made.
>
> Make a note of the old question on your new one, (and explain why any answers that the old one has are no good to you).
>
> If appropriate (and if you have enough rep), vote to close the old one as a duplicate of your new one, and add a comment on the old one stating what you have done with a link to your new one.

Seems like good advice all around, whether the new question exists yet or not!